# jquery dialog popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, popup

I am working on my application using spring.
My objective is:
when user click on a button to save data in database (I use ajax), i want to display dialog popup with info whether transaction was commit or not:

My code:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit"  id="btnSubmit" onclick="showDialog();" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
                                    data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#exampleModal"
                                    data-whatever="@mdo">Send</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="dialog">


                        </div>
```

and the Javascript looks like this:

```
$function()
{
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        modal : true,
        title : "Details",
           width: 500,
            height: 400,
        buttons : {
            Close : function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
});

$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/addUser",
            async : true,
            dataType : "text",
            success : function(d) {
                $("#dialog").dialog('open');
                $("#dialog").html('<p>' + d + '</p>');

                return false;
            }
        });
    });



}
```

After saving in database I receive my message but on another page.
I suppose that there is problem with dialog code.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your javascript has a syntax error (`$function()` -> `$(function()` and closing paren). If that is present in your actual code, none of your javascript is actually executing.

Comment: @Jason P. Thank you for your remark, but I still a problem. After saving data ajax goes to another page and popup doesnt display